# Use generic for property name in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type the following function:

```
const tabulate = <T, U, K extends string, V extends string>(
  key: K,
  value: V,
  reducefn: (result: U, nextValue: T) => U,
  initialValue: U,
  array: { [K]: string; [V]: T }[]
) => {
  return array.reduce((result, nextValue) => {
    result[nextValue[key]] = reducefn(
      result[nextValue[key]] ?? initialValue,
      nextValue[value]
    );
    return result;
  }, {});
};

tabulate("name", "value", (a, b) => a + b, 0, [
  { name: "John", value: 20 },
  { name: "Kate", value: 10 },
  { name: "Kate", value: 30 },
]); // {John: 20, Kate: 40}
```

The idea is that `key` and `value` can be arbitrary strings, however, each object in `array` has to have two properties with names matching those strings. However, the code above does not work. Specifically, it is the subsetting on the generic that seems to be the problem:

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)
'K' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

Any ideas - is it even possible to use generics like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, it's not even all that complicated:

```
function tabulate<T extends {}, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T>(
    name: K1,
    value: K2,
    init: T[K2],
    reducer: (a: T[K2], b: T[K2]) => T[K2],
    arr: T[],
) {
    const result: { [k: string]: T[K2] } = {};
    return arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
        if (name in obj) {
            const key = obj[name];
            if (typeof key === 'string') {
                acc[key] = reducer(acc[key] ?? init, obj[value]);
            }
        }

        return acc;
    }, result);
}

tabulate("name", "value", 0, (a, b) => a + b, [
  { name: "John", value: 20 },
  { name: "Kate", value: 10 },
  { name: "Kate", value: 30 },
]);
```

We only need three generics: the object type from the array, and one for each of the keys. I think you were over-thinking it :)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAhgIxAGxVApgHgBVFcAPPMAEwGdEBvAXwBpEBpARhPNytoGtcATzjBEhFqwBMXCjUQDhowgD4AFAChEWxGBQBbXAC427Jpu0A3FJhBG2ks9sQwwMKMcIBtKQF1H2gCdcShAIXADjVRQPb0k-RDQY3wBKRABeZTFYv3MtFACIrJzUulzECARqKEQg6ix3ekRPPmMqgJcAcx8kuMQGdPoGAG4yoKgQAKR8gIA6IJCw1SiICBY4NAArVIz6MqcYUVVdA2ckda3dpyvtCrAq+SEB889j3B8R6+uDxFUoQQAHXAiB6CdJpNKIADkbU6kJKe0+ThQK2aQh8A3moXCywgqME6IA-ATTm41ptPFYbG9kh9EdoGAitAzGTVcONJohkRBaUyWLV6jT1MzbtQ4JhcDNMHAOr90FgcLhVAAiV5KlhKym2NWIAAMLCiLDQ20yKEQAGoEixPOY6Dp9HYlQApOAACzA2s1dkkOr6-ltr2MStYCo91lsxnYPuYNrtBkDwbwoapxgAzFGzD5koKgA)

## Edit

As Thomas points out in the comments, there is no need for the combining function to be limited to the input type. For the low low price of one more generic you can have it all:

```
function tabulate<T extends {}, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T, U>(
    name: K1,
    value: K2,
    init: U,
    reducer: (a: U, b: T[K2]) => U,
    arr: T[],
) {
    const result = {} as Record<T[K1] & string, U>;
    return arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
        if (name in obj) {
            const key = obj[name];
            if (typeof key === 'string') {
                acc[key] = reducer(acc[key] ?? init, obj[value]);
            }
        }

        return acc;
    }, result);
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NV35Gm)

Comment: You're limiting the use very much when you limit it's ReturnType to the type of the values it processes. see https://tsplay.dev/NV35Gm